# Help solve a computational complexity problem

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity

Find the tight computational time ($\Theta$ notation) complexity of the following function

[image]

Of course an exact solution is $\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{3{n^3}} {\frac{{2{n^3}}}{i}} $, but I am not able to solve this summation. Anyone can help with this summation or is there better way? Thank you!

Comment: I have not looked at the program, only at the sum in your post. Look up *harmonic number* (Wikipedia). The sum of the reciprocals of the integers from $1$ to $M$ is approximately $\ln M$. (You can find tighter estimates in the article, but this should be good enough.) Let $M=3n^3$.

Comment: The runtime of the algorithm shown is $O(n^6)$.

Comment: The sum you display is **not** an estimate of the runtime! Perhaps it's the value that the function computes — I'd have to think about it. But those are very different things. The runtime of a function is, strictly speaking, an integer, as it counts number of times that "basic instructions" (such as the innermost) are executed.

Comment: @BrianO Thanks for reply. The runtime is actually no more than $O(n^5)$, but the question requires a tight bound.

Comment: @BrianO Sorry that there is a typo in the picture. it is not ${2n^3/2}$ but $2i^3/2$ in the second iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You can get as
good an approximation as you want from
$\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{3{n^3}} {\frac{{2n^3}}{i}}
=2{n^3}\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{3{n^3}} {\frac{{1}}{i}}
=2{n^3}H_{3n^3}
=2{n^3}(\ln(3n^3)+\gamma+...)
=2{n^3}(3\ln(n)+\ln(3)+\gamma+...)
$.

Comment: BUT how is this the number of steps executed?

Comment: OP asked for help with the summation. This is my help.

Comment: Fair enough, no problem.